# What does the phrase HY''D mean?

Tags: death, translation

What does "Hashem yikom damam" mean? Does it imply Hashem will take revenge on the murderer?
Being that we believe every soul taken was a decision made by Hashem, even if it's impossible to understand. What is the role of Hashem avenging the blood?

Comment: among others cf אָבִֽינוּ מַלְכֵּֽנוּ נְקוֹם לְעֵינֵֽינוּ נִקְמַת דַּם־עֲבָדֶֽיךָ הַשָּׁפוּךְ:

Comment: [Devarim 32:43](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.32.43?lang=bi&lang2=he): "כי דם עבדיו יקום ונקם ישיב לצריו".

Comment: https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/were-the-egyptians-punished-for-doing-gods-will-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter

Comment: I think this question is "if all death comes about by Hashem's decree, i.e He is to blame, then why does He take _revenge_ on the fulfillers of His decree?"